# Polling SNMP Messages Remotely

Tags: linux, snmp

I'm trying to monitor a server (Ubuntu 12.04) via SNMP remotely. I have edited the snmpd.conf file and added a IP block to the readonly section. When I try to test SNMP locally, I can see that it works. Here is the command I used to test my SNMP daemon locally.

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c <comname> localhost system
```

The problem is, from remote hosts I can not see any messages. Below is the command I used.

```
snmpwalk -v1 -c <comname> <IPtoBeMonitored>
```

The error message I get is;

```
Timeout: No Response from <IPtoBeMonitored>
```

I don't have a firewall. What do you think might be the cause of this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run 'netstat -an | grep :161' - if you don't see the address of your Ethernet adapter (i.e. only 127.0.0.1:161) then you need to configure agentaddress in your snmpd.conf.

Comment: I found out that Ubuntu keeps a file at /etc/default/snmpd which has a line as below.

_SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid 127.0.0.1'_

Deleting the 127.0.0.1 from the line above and restarting SNMP daemon did the trick. 

Thank you rnxrx and @Joel K. You were both right.

Comment: @patrician this information does not appear to be accurate for 12.04. I experience the same issue but my default/snmpd does not have 127.0.0.1 listed there...

Answer (score 0):

Check your snmpd.conf -- are you perhaps only binding on loopback?